# Creating a script that Moves Computer to an AD OU and Deletes them from SCCM From CSV File

Tags: powershell

I am basically trying to combine two Powershell scripts that were provided to me. I have most of the script to work together where it imports the computer names from a CSV file. It first moves them to a specific OU in AD and it then deletes them from SCCM.

However, on the last section of the script seems to not work perfectly.The issues starts at

**"# Read the csv file for computer records"**

For example, I have a computer named "SP3-TEST" but the logs return the error "@{CN=SP3-TEST} not found in SCCM"

For reasons not known to me, it adds the @{CN=} to the computer name.

I have tried to edit the scripts to use only one variable for each need. I am coming from creating batch scripts 90% of my time so maybe I am missing something extremely simple.

```
#Run script as admin
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot
$fname = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name | Out-String
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""$fname""' -Verb RunAs}";

#Importing AD Module
Write-Host " Importing AD Module..... "
import-module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host " Importing Move List..... "

# Reading list of computers from csv and loading into variable
$MoveList = Import-Csv "PC_Move_List.csv"

# defining Target Path
$TargetOU = 'OU=RetiredComputers,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com'
$countPC    = ($movelist).count
Write-Host " Starting import computers ..."

foreach ($Computer in $MoveList){    
    Write-Host " Moving Computer Accounts..." 
    Get-ADComputer $Computer.CN | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $TargetOU
    Get-ADComputer $Computer.CN | Disable-ADAccount  
}   

$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$log      = "$ScriptDir\clientremoval.log"
$date     = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"

"---------------------  Script executed on $date (dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss) ---------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
#try import SCCM Module ,if error catch it.
Try
{
Import-Module (Join-Path $(Split-Path $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH) ConfigurationManager.psd1)
$SiteCode = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider CMSITE
$SMSProvider=$sitecode.SiteServer
Set-Location "$($SiteCode.Name):\"
}
Catch
{
 "[ERROR]`t SCCM Module couldn't be loaded. Script will exit!" | Out-File $log -append
 Exit 1
 }
 # Read the csv file for computer records
 ForEach ($Computer in $MoveList)
  {
   $CN=Get-CMDevice -Name $Computer

   if ($name) 
   {
    try {
       "$date [INFO]`t $name found in SCCM " | Out-File $log -append
       Remove-CMDevice -name $Computer -force 
       "$date [INFO]`t $name removed from SCCM " | Out-File $log -append
        }
    catch
      {"$date [INFO]`t $name found in SCCM but unable to delete record.Check further " | Out-File $log -append
      }
      }
   else
    { "$date [INFO]`t $Computer not found in SCCM " | Out-File $log -append}
   }

   $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
Write-Host " Completed Move List "

Write-Host " $countPC  Computers has been moved "
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

The Powershell script should be trying to delete SP3-TEST not @{CN=SP3-TEST}

Below is the original script.

```
    <# 
AUTHOR  : Eswar Koneti 
DATE    : 18-Nov-2016
COMMENT : This script will read notepad file for client computers
         ,check if they exist and remove from SCCM .
VERSION : 1.0
#>
# Determine script location and create log file to store the results
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$log      = "$ScriptDir\clientremoval.log"
$date     = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"

"---------------------  Script executed on $date (dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss) ---------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
#try import SCCM Module ,if error catch it.
Try
{
Import-Module (Join-Path $(Split-Path $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH) ConfigurationManager.psd1)
$SiteCode = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider CMSITE
$SMSProvider=$sitecode.SiteServer
Set-Location "$($SiteCode.Name):\"
}
Catch
{
 "[ERROR]`t SCCM Module couldn't be loaded. Script will exit!" | Out-File $log -append
 Exit 1
 }
 # Read the notepad file for client records
 ForEach ($client in Get-Content $ScriptDir"\clients.txt")
  {
   $CN=Get-CMDevice -Name $client
   $name=$CN.Name
   if ($name) 
   {
    try {
       "$date [INFO]`t $name found in SCCM " | Out-File $log -append
       Remove-CMDevice -name $client -force 
       "$date [INFO]`t $name removed from SCCM " | Out-File $log -append
        }
    catch
      {"$date [INFO]`t $name found in SCCM but unable to delete record.Check further " | Out-File $log -append
      }
      }
   else
    { "$date [INFO]`t $client not found in SCCM " | Out-File $log -append}
   }
```

Comment: Where does `$name` come from? You never define that anywhere

Comment: Then change it to `Remove-CMDevice -name $Computer.CN -force`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I tried that as well but lo luck. It still provides @{CN=SP3-TEST}. I added the original script which does Provide "SP3-TEST" successfully.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You are correct. I am still struggling a bit with defining variables unfortunately. In the original script (which I provided above) I can see that it defines it by  $name=$CN.Name. However, I am struggling to see where $CN.Name is showed originally. My train of thought its that

$CN=Get-CMDevice -Name $client

is the same as $CN.Name after it runs Get.CMDevice and retries the "name" from $client

Comment: Ok, you didn't define `$name`, you skipped that line, so the `If($name)` line should always fail and you should always see the "XXX not found in SCCM" message in your logs. Change the line in the `Else` block from `$date [INFO]\`t $Computer not found in SCCM` to `$date [INFO]\`t $($Computer.CN) not found in SCCM` and see if that doesn't fix your logging issue. Also change the `If($name)` to `If($Computer.CN)`